# AngularJs : How to know if an URL's change is from adress bar or from component action

Tags: angularjs, url, angularjs-rootscope

I'm creating an AngularJs web app and I need to know if an user enter an url in the address bar. In this case I will destroy the current context to initiate a new one. 
I tried to use the `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {});` function
but it seems there is no way to differenciate if the change comes from the user who entered a url in the adress bar or if it comes from a action in the apge (button, link, enter on a form, ...).
Can I differenciate both case ? Or should I re-think my URL handling (Any suggestion) ?

Comment: Not sure it can be done through any contentional means, you might be able to check the oldUrl or oldState to know where it came from. If this was a direct entry in the browser, the old might be null. You can simply send some data via the click or submit to identify if its from a button. However, The question you need to ask yourself is why do I need to know this information and why does it matter that I find the origin. If this is so important and cruicial to application flow, perhaps you need to consider an alternative Perhaps you can share more insight on why you need this.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you writing your own router? Or are you using` ngRoute` or `ui-router`? What is the code doing with other events such as `$locationChangeStart`, `$routeChangeStart`, or `$stateChangeStart`? With UI-Router 1.X Transition hooks? Wouldn't it be more polite to ask the user before destroying information instead of doing it automatically?